# Changing Service to type Automatic through GPO not working

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Currently I have a service "WINRM" (other wise known as Windows Remote Management) that is by default set to a startup type of normal. I created a group policy object on the server to change all the machines to change the startup type of this service to automatic. I did this 2 ways in both the computer->preferences AND the computer->policy way. When I run a GPUpdate /force on the test computer and then go to restart it I see the service isnt started and that the service is not set to a startup type of automatic, I have other GPO's that are working so I know I have it assigned to the right group, any help is appreciated, thank you!

My setup: server is windows 2012 server, test pc is windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, the reason was because of a denied WMI filter. Being a nooby with GPO's I did not realize you were able to create a filter to apply to the GPO so that only computers matching the filter would actually apply the GPO.

**How I figured it out**,

You can run a event viewer on the computer by hitting start and then typing in "event". After this go to the GPO logs (Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> GroupPolicy -> Operational) from there you will be able to see information about the execution of your GPO's.

**The other way** to get this information is to type "gpresult /r" in command line and then you should be able to see information that way too, this is my favorite out of the two since its quicker to get too and easier to read all of the information at once.

Anyway this concludes the answer, I hope this is able to help others out that are beginning and learning about GPO's.